# React, is there a way to play sound on useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, html5-audio

I installed use-sound,

```
const [ play ] = useSound(sound, {interrupt: true})
```

then I want to play a sound when theres a data change

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (prevData.length < newData.length) {
      play()
    }
  }, [ prevData,newData ])
```

It's pretty strange cause sometimes it works.. More often locally than online..

Actually i'd like to play the sound  even if the window is  not in focus.
And in this case, again sometimes it works..

But I can't figure why this is not stable since the setup is pretty simple.

Comment: Could you place a console.log before play() to check how many times play is called?

Answer (score 1):

i thinks would be better if u make seperate component just for sound like this:
[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-andras-lodvz?file=/src/Sound.js).

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import useSound from "use-sound";
import beep from "./beep-08b.mp3";

export default function Sound({ counter }) {
  const [play] = useSound(beep, { interrupt: true });

  useEffect(() => {
    play();
  }, [counter, play]);
  return null;
}
```

Comment: was thinking to do it later  .. but will it solves the pb? did you have it?

Comment: yes it works. check codesandbox link , i did share.

Comment: yes it works on your example. i may have another pb. thanks